How to integrate a glossary of abbreviations into LangChain for better SQL query generation (NL2SQL)?
I am using LangChain to interface with an Oracle database where many column names include abbreviations. I want to provide LangChain with a glossary that explains these abbreviations to improve its ability to accurately select the right columns for queries. How can I incorporate a glossary into my current LangChain setup to give it this additional context? Note that in my corporate environment simply renaming the columns is not an option.
This is how I currently use LangChain for it to answer my natural language questions in natrual language:
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent 
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit

toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=chat_client)
agent_executor = create_sql_agent(llm=chat_client,
                                  toolkit=toolkit,
                                  agent_type="openai-tools",
                                  verbose=True,
                                  return_intermediate_steps=True)
agent_executor.invoke("How many orders from Singapore did we have in March 2023?")

I'd like to add a glossary that includes entries like { "CST_ID": "Customer ID", "PRDCT_NUM": "Product Number" } to help LangChain understand these abbreviations better.
What modifications are needed in the LangChain configuration or code to make this possible?
